# Is there a LINQ-like alternative to looping in JavaScript when looking for an object with a specific property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, sharepoint

Currently my code looks like this:

```
    var arrayListEnum = list.getEnumerator();

    while (arrayListEnum.moveNext()) {

        var listItem = arrayListEnum.get_current();
        if (listItem.get_id() == id) { 

            //stuff(listItem);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Maybe I'm just spoiled by C#, but I don't really like the look of this. In JavaScript or jQuery (I'd rather not include an entire other library), is there a way for me to do something like:

```
var item = (from items in list.getEnumerator() 
            where items.get_id() == id
            select items);

//stuff(item);
```

or

```
var item = list.getEnumerator().Where(item => item.get_id() == id);
//stuff(item);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try [jinq.js](http://www.jinqjs.com/)

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it somewhat elegantly without including an entire library. If not I'll probably just leave it as a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are getting [list item collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244833.aspx) from list, in that case if you interested only in getting *list item by its id*, then i would suggest utilize [SP.List.getItemById Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246019.aspx), for example:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
ctx.load(item);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
       console.log(item.get_id());
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

> Note: from performance perspective the advantage here that there is no
>   need to request list item collection and then filter item on the
>   client side

Below are provided some examples that demonstrate how to find/filter list item in collection by property

1) Using `getEnumerator` method

```
function findListItem(items,propertyName,propertyValue)
{
   var e = items.getEnumerator();
   while (e.moveNext()) {
      var listItem = e.get_current();
      if (listItem.get_item(propertyName) == propertyValue) { 
          return listItem        
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

2) Using `for` statement

```
function findListItem(items,propertyName,propertyValue)
{
   for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count();i++) {
      var listItem = items.get_item(i);
      if (listItem.get_item(propertyName) == propertyValue) { 
          return listItem        
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

3)Using [filter() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
//returns array(!)
function findListItem(items,propertyName,propertyValue)
{
    return items.get_data().filter(function(item){
       if (item.get_item(propertyName) == propertyValue) { 
          return item        
       }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is in an array, you can kind-of use `Array.filter`.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var item = array.filter(function (element) {
    return element === 3;
})[0];
console.log(item); // 3
```

This will put the result in `item` and leave the original array untouched.
There's the caveat that `Array.filter` returns an array, not a single element. In your case you want a single element, hence `[0]` at the end of the function call.

For browsers which do not implement `Array.filter` the MDN page has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

*Quick edit/addition*: Another caveat is that this walks through the whole collection, even after the matching element is found.